# Why does using '.' instead of '[]' to call a property of an object not work in my filter function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have a question here:
why cant i use "." instead of "[]",to call a property of the object??

```
function filter(array, prop) {

  var result = array.map(x=>{
    return x[prop]
  })

  return result
}

filter([{ name: 'TV LCD', price: 100}, { name: 'PC', price: 500 }],"name")

//[ 'TV LCD', 'PC' ]
```

```
 function filter(array, prop) {

  var result = array.map(x=>{
    if(x.name===prop){
      return x
    }
  })

  return result
}

filter([{ name: 'TV LCD', price: 100}, { name: 'PC', price: 500 }],"name")


//[undefined,undefined]
```

sorry for my english :/

i want the "name" property of the object, but in the console shows: [undefined,undefined]

Comment: In what programming language? Is this javascript? perl? Python? Kotlin?

Comment: Because `x.name` literally means the property called "`name`" of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `x.name` is "TV LCD" or "PC" and `prop` is "name", so `x.name === prop` never evaluates to true.

```js
if(x.name===prop){ // x.name is never "name"; always evaluates to false
  return x
}
```

The syntax below is the equivalent of `x["name"]` which is the same as `x.name`.

```js
return x[prop]
```

Comment: I did some research and found that it is related to the [bracket notation],
i suppose it is for the iteration of the .map()
ty btw